# Java Fuel SDK ETClient class causing NullPointerException

Tags: marketing-cloud, java

I know this is caused by a `null` value, however I'm not sure why it's `null`. Have I not instantiated ETClient correctly? Or overlooked something else?

```
package exacttarget.api;

import com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          // specifiy client ID and secret
          ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
          configuration.set("clientId", "abc123");
          configuration.set("clientSecret", "xyz");

          // instantiate ETClient object
          ETClient client = new ETClient(configuration); 

          ETFilter myFilter = new ETFilter();

          ETResponse response = client.retrieve(ETSubscriber.class, myFilter);
          System.out.println(response);
        }
        catch (ETSdkException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles, using Gradle for the build. But when I run the jar:

> ```
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient).
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
> log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:82)
>     at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
>     at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.PartnerAPI.<init>(PartnerAPI.java:49)
>     at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection.<init>(ETSoapConnection.java:88)
>     at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection.<init>(ETSoapConnection.java:178)
>     at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.<init>(ETClient.java:158)
>     at exacttarget.api.MyClass.main(FetchBounces.java:15)
> ```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to retrieve?  You're not setting any attributes on the `myFilter` object before you immediately attempt a retrieve.

Comment: I'll eventually want to retrieve a few different things, but I'll be starting with retrieving an individual by their email. This error makes me thing I'm not instantiating the `ETClient` correctly, but from what I am seeing in the docs it looks correct. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error, and I solve it.
It seems some resource is conflicting between depending on libs.

I imagine you create one jar-file gathering all libs.
If you change the build to refer jars using class-path, it will works.

```
jar {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'title',
                   'Implementation-Version': 1.0,
                   'Main-Class' : 'your main class',
                   'Class-Path' : 'every reference jars'
                   }
}
```